# How to get chart data points value with equal or less than to highlight those data

Tags: c#, mschart

I'm looking to change my chart series data points if there is an error values. I want to set rule to highlight those data points like below. Please help to get below code working.

```
// Find first point with a Y2 value of equal or less than 10.
                var dataPoint = Chart1.Series[1].Points.Where(x => x.YValues <= 10); 
                foreach (DataPoint dt in dataPoint)
                {
                    dt.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dot; 
                    dt.Color = Color.Red;                    
                }
```

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: Yes Taw, Thank you very much

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..

Answer (score 0):

[`DataPoint.YValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapoint.yvalues(v=vs.110).aspx) is an array.

> The YValues property is used to set the Y-values of data points.
>
> Only one Y-value per point is required for all chart types except
>   **bubble, candlestick** and **stock charts**. These chart types require more
>   than one Y-value because one data point consists of multiple values.
>   For example, to plot one stock chart column, four values are required:
>   high, low, open and close values.
>
> The YValues property returns an array of double values when used to
>   retrieve the Y-values.
>
> Important   The YValuesPerPoint property determines the maximum number
>   of Y-values that all data points in a Series can have. If you specify
>   more than the allowable number of Y-values, an exception will be
>   raised.

Unless you are using one of the above special [`ChartTypes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.series.charttype(v=vs.110).aspx) you always will want to use the first element. So simply write:

```
var dataPoint = Chart1.Series[1].Points.Where(x => x.YValues[0] <= 10);
```

If you do use one of the three multiple Y-Values chart types you could, depending on the situation for example write this:

```
var dataPoint = Chart1.Series[1].Points.Where(x => x.YValues.Max() <= 10);
```

or this:

```
var dataPoint = Chart1.Series[1].Points.Where(x => x.YValues.Min() <= 10);
```

Comment: Is there any way to take whole array which is <=10 in `dataPoint`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. The upper elements are empty and cannot be filled unless the ChartType allows/demands it. What ChartType do you use? See the last paragraph!

Comment: Thanks TaW, This works - `var dataPoint = Chart1.Series[1].Points.Where(x => x.YValues.Min() <= 10); `